# Have script only work on certain sheet not all on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, eventtrigger

I need this script to work on just a named sheet, not all of them please in google sheets

```
function onEdit(e) {

var row = e.range.getRow();

var col = e.range.getColumn();

if(col == 6){

e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,7).setValue(new Date());

}

}
```

It applies to all sheets not just one

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your needs:

```
 function onEdit(e) {

  if (e.range.columnStart == 6) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("YourSheet");
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var range = sheet.getRange (row,7);

  range.setValue(new Date());

    }
  }
```

Just change **YourSheet** in the script to your own sheet name.